# onclick show date field and on select date hide date field

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a date displaying as plain text. when I click on change button datepicker should appear below and when I select some date, the date picker should be hidden. and the date in the plane text should be changed.

```
<span id="display-date"> <?php  echo $sdate; ?></span>
<span id="d1" onClick="showdate()"> change </span>
<div  id="datepicker"></div>  

 <script>
  $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
 </script>
```

This is what all I have. 
Initially (on page load), The div with id="datepicker" should be hidden.
When I click on 'change' with id="d1", div with id="datepicker" should be shown.
and when I select a date, I should be again hidden and $sdate variable should take that value. So the content in span with id="display-date" should be changed.

Comment: The use of "urgent" is inappropriate. It is clear a majority rejects the idea that questions are urgent simply because the poster says that they are urgent.  You might read    http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137486/initial-bounty-for-urgent-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do:

```
<span id="display-date"> <?php  echo $sdate; ?></span>
<span id="d1"> change </span>
<div  id="datepicker" style="display:none;"></div>
```

and js

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateStr, dateObj) {
        $("#display-date").html(dateStr);
        $("#datepicker").hide();
    }
});
$("span#d1").click(function() {
    $("#datepicker").show();
});
```

Demo :: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cXSHL/)

Answer (score 2):

You want to check out the jQuery `datepicker`: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/h7wau/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" value="2013-08-11" />
```

JS:

```
$("#datepicker").click(function () {
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```